# How do I get the just the number from a SQL table where it is stored like this <PersonNumber>013870</PersonNumber>

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that stores the information like this, ABC, and I just want the text in between.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Also, I see you removed the XML sample data from your post.  Provide sample data and expected results.

Comment: The column name is called XMLREQBODY and in this column there is a long line of xml data and I just want certain values out of it to put in a .csv file.

Answer (score 2):

simple demo

```
declare @test table 
(
    xmlElement varchar(1000)
)
insert into @test
values ('<PersonNumber>013870</PersonNumber>')

-- select numbers from xml in the given format
select 
    cast(SUBSTRING(xmlElement, 15 , CHARINDEX('</PersonNumber>',xmlElement)-15) as int) -- 15 is position where number starts, because 14 is legth of <PersonNumber>
from @test 

-- result is 13870
```

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle there is *[*REGEXP_SUBSTR*](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/functions116.htm)* you can use it if you are oracle to get the number you want ans this is an example for you:

```
SELECT
  REGEXP_SUBSTR('500 Oracle Parkway, Redwood Shores, CA',
                ',[^,]+,') "REGEXPR_SUBSTR"
  FROM DUAL;

REGEXPR_SUBSTR
-----------------
, Redwood Shores,
```

Comment: You probably posted this before the OP included the `sql-server` tag. But in Oracle it might be better to do something like the following (using `REGEXP_REPLACE()`) so as not to get extraneous characters (which your solution does - it has extra commas): `SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('<PersonNumber>013870</PersonNumber>', '<[^>]+>') FROM dual;` http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/40183

Answer (score 0):

If PersonNumber is fixed length you can simply use substring function.

Otherwise use

select Substring(PersonNumber, Patindex('%>%',PersonNumber) + 1, Patindex('%< /%',PersonNumber) - Patindex('%>%',PersonNumber)-1)

Comment: Thank you very much. How do I add it to my script below. The column I am pulling from is called XMLREQBODY                                           Select
  XMLREQKEY
, XMLREQBODY
, FAILEDXMLBODYID
, FAILEDXMLDATAID

FROM FAILEDXMLDATA

Answer (score 0):

Try this as Sample:

```
DECLARE @z VARCHAR(32) = ',ukasd10,';
SELECT REPLACE(SUBSTRING(@z, CHARINDEX(',', @z), LEN(@z)), ',', '') AS Sample
```

and use this logic wherever you want...thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With SQL Server, you can use an XML method if the column contains well-formed XML:

```
SELECT CAST(YourColumn AS xml).value('/Request[1]/Schedule[1]/Employees[1]/PersonIdentity[1]/PersonNumber[1]', 'int') AS PersonNumber
FROM dbo.YourTable;
```

Comment: Unfortunately the column has multiple XML tags.....<Request Action="AddScheduleItems" > <Schedule> <Employees> <PersonIdentity> <PersonNumber>013870</PersonNumber> </PersonIdentity> </Employees> <QueryDateSpan>02/27/2015-02/27/2015</QueryDateSpan> <ScheduleItems> <SchedulePayCodeEdit> <AmountInTime>8.00</AmountInTime> <DisplayTime>7:00</DisplayTime> <Employee> <PersonIdentity> <PersonNumber>013870</PersonNumber> </PersonIdentity> </Employee> <PayCodeName>Vacation</PayCodeName> <StartDate>02/27/2015</StartDate> </SchedulePayCodeEdit> </ScheduleItems> </Schedule> </Request>

Comment: So you have multiple PersonNumber elements in the same xml?  Are you expecting all of them or just the first.  I suggest you edit your question to provide the XML and expected results.  I updated my answer to show how to get the first but we need your requirements if you need multiples (e.g. delimited list).